# Accessing a named view from a template in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

Suppose I have two Apps AppA and AppB

```
   |_AppB
    |  |_urls.py # url(r'^create/', views.user_profile, name="name_user_profile"), 
    | 
    |_AppA
       |_urls.py
       |_templates
             |_file.html
```

Now in file.html I have something like this

```
{% block content %}

    Success !!!

      goto  <a href={% url `name_user_profile` % }> Manage Profile </a>

{% endblock %}
```

However name_user_profile cant be recognised ? Is there anything i have to do to get it recognised ?

**Update:**

This is what I have done so far

In my main app urls.py (the one with settings.py). I added the following

```
url(r'^profile/', include("UserProfile.urls" , namespace="UserProfile" , app_name="UserProfile")),
```

Now in my UserProfile app where the view is located I have this

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.user_profile, name="name_user_profile"),
    ]
```

and the template which which needs to call that view is located in the 3rd app
called accounts which has this

```
  goto  <a href={% url 'UserProfile:name_user_profile' % }> Manage Profile </a>
```

But that does not seem to work

Comment: Your syntax appears to be wrong. Try: `<a href={% url 'name_user_profile' %}>`

Comment: thanks for the correction I fixed it but its still not showing up

Comment: Is there anything i need to do to tell it to look into the App.urls.py for this name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your apps reference different `urls.py` files, in order to use named URLs you will need to access each one with its own namespace.

[Check out the example in the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs). There is a `urls.py` file that uses `include('polls.urls')`. Then, in the actual Polls app, there are a couple of named URLs, `index` and `detail`. Since they're inside an app those urls can be accessed by using their namespace - `{% url 'polls:index' %}` and `{% urls 'polls:detail' %}` respectively.

If you are working before Django 1.9, you have to specifically supply the `namespace` argument after the `include` statement. Starting in 1.9 Django automatically uses the app name for the namespace when you `include` a urls.py file from an app.

Comment: That does not seem to work `{% url 'AppB:name_user_profile' % }`

Comment: The auto-detected namespace will be a lowercase version of the app name, are you following that format or are you capitalizing like in this example?

Comment: I am capitalizing- should i use all lower case ?

Comment: I believe it should look identical to however it is in your `installed_apps` setting.

Comment: That is what i am doing in the above example and its not working

Comment: Please read the example docs I linked. This is how you access urls.py files across apps.